# Useful Intellij Live Templates

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In the same manner as the Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates, and having converted to Intellij I'm wondering whether there are similar useful code templates that people use.

I've setup the slf4j import as follows:

- Abbreviation: slog
- Section: output
- Edit Variables: CLASS_NAME -> className()
- Applicable in Java: declaration

and the template text is:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);
```

Are there other useful Live Templates that people use?

Comment: Code faster with Intellij IDEA [live templates](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2014/01/14/code-faster-with-intellij-idea-live-templates/a).

Answer (score 2):

With Java 7 you can use the `lookup` method in the `MethodHandles`class to simplify the logging template.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if it's not a live template, I suggest you give [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) a try. It's got the @Slf4j annotation you can use to get an instance variable named "log" which is a full-fledged logger. Just import the lombok dependency and enable pre-processing. Done